# Gave regex for allowing only alphabets and a space but its not validating for numpad

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, validation

Althought I've given regex for name its allowing numpad numbers. Similar issue in mobile number field, its allowing special characters although I've given regex. Why is this not working? Any help would be appreciated

```
let namecheck = false;
let mobcheck = false;
$("#fname").keydown(function (ev) {

        var namekey = String.fromCharCode(ev.which);

        var input = this.value
        var prev = input.length - 1
        let nameregex = /^[A-Za-z ]$/

        if (ev.which != 8 && ev.which != 46) {                 //to allow backspace and del
            if (!nameregex.test(namekey) || (input[prev] == " " && namekey == " ")) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            }
        }

        if (input.length < 2) {
            namecheck = false
            $("#error1").text("Enter at least 3 characters")
        }
        else {
            $("#error1").text("")
            namecheck = true
        }
    })

    $("#fmob").keydown(function (ev) {

        let mobkey = String.fromCharCode(ev.which)
        let mob = this.value;
        let mobregex = /^[0-9]$/
        if (ev.which != 8 && ev.which != 46) {                 //to allow backspace and del
            if (!mobregex.test(mobkey)) {
                ev.preventDefault()
            }
        }

        if (mob.length < 9) {
            $("#error2").text("Mobile number should be at least 10 digits")
            mobcheck = false
        }
        if (mob.length == 9) {
            $("#error2").text("")
            mobcheck = true
        }
        if (mob.length == 10) {
            if (ev.which != 8 && ev.which != 46) {
                ev.preventDefault()
            }
        }


    })
})
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z\s]+` this is the regex for matching letters and spaces only.

Comment: @DedaDev I'm comparing each key during keydown() thats why I omitted the '+' sign. But I've tried giving that too, the result is same. It allows numpad numbers for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex expression will not prevent numpad it seems. I would suggest you check the codes 96 through 105 if you want to block 0-9 on the numpad.

Prevent numpad:

```
  if (ev.which >= 96 && ev.which <= 105) {
     ev.preventDefault();
  }
```

---

Use `event.key` to get the actual key so the regex number will not accept letters or special characters.

```
  const key = ev.key
  const numberReg = /^[0-9]$/
  if(!numberReg.test(key)){
      // prevent letters and special cahracters
      ev.preventDefault()
  }
```

Comment: Yes this works for not allowing the numpad in name field. Thank you. 
But I am also facing a similar and weird problem with regular expression for allowing only number keys. I gave [0-9] for it but its also allowing the special characters above 0-9 keys on the keyboard. Do you have any suggestion for that too? Cause there arent key codes for some characters like &. I wonder why there arent many people asking about this

Comment: Use the `event.key` so you can properly test against the regex number and it should fix your issue. 

I updated the answer to include that as the solution for the problem you are having with the numbers and special characters.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! This actually fixed it

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could have help!